# exports is not defined within Hybrid angular app

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular5

I am working over Angularjs and angular 6 integration with in a hybrid app.

tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

However, I am getting below error at my app.module.js file

```
exports is not defined in app.module.js at
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

I have removed commonjs from tsconfig. Still ther above error is coming up.

It is also giving a redline over "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ]
Not sure why?
Pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

With angular 6, the tsconfig.json file generated by angular itself is:

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Try with above code, hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: It is still giving the same error. and generating red line over "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", and  "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]                                                                                                     
     in tsconfig file.

Comment: I am creating a hybrid app using angular js and angular 6 so need to make configurations to tsconfig.jcon file.

Comment: Actually, that was the working code from my project, maybe for angularjs those configurations differ.